# MySQL Case/If/Then

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am trying to build a query in MySQL, where I have a numeric stock level of something and depending on what that stock level is, I want it to return another value that would be a colour code.

E.g. If the stock level is <0 then EMPTY if stock level is Between 0 and 1000 then RED, If stock level is Between 1000 and 5000 then YELLOW, If Stock level is Between 5000 and 10000 then GREEN, If Stock level is >10000 then GREEN.

So here is my example.  I have a Beer table that holds info on the Beer and a BeerStock table that holds the Stock Values.

```
SELECT Beer.Beer, Beer.Brewery, Beer.Style, Beer.ABV, Beer.Hops, Beer.SRM,
Sum(BeerStock.Quantity)
FROM Beer, BeerStock
Where Beer.Beer = BeerStock.Beer
```

That would give me something like this:

```
Beer1 Brewery1 Style1 5%, 3, 10, 1238
```

And I want

```
Beer1 Brewery1 Style1 5%, 3, 10, 1238 YELLOW
```

I can't seem to figure this out at all, should I be using a CASE or can I use an IF/THEN type of thing?

My SQL skills are rusty, normally I use Access and mess with the auto-generated SQL rather than writing from scratch...I can cope with the basics of MySQL but not this kind of stuff!

Any advice/pointers appreciated....

Thanks

Andy

Comment: yes a CASE statement will work.  also EMPTY = NULL and the colors will likely be hex values if you will use them in some html output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thin you mean that if the `stock > 1000` then another color `not green`.

```
SELECT  Beer.Beer, 
        Beer.Brewery, 
        Beer.Style, 
        Beer.ABV, 
        Beer.Hops, 
        Beer.SRM,
        Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) totalQuantity,
        CASE WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) < 0 THEN ''
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 1000 AND 4999 THEN 'Yellow'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 5000 AND 9999 THEN 'GREEN'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) >= 10000 THEN 'Another Color' 
        END
FROM    Beer
        INNER JOIN BeerStock
            ON Beer.Beer = BeerStock.Beer
-- Where    ..other conditions..
```

but if you really mean that,

```
SELECT  Beer.Beer, 
        Beer.Brewery, 
        Beer.Style, 
        Beer.ABV, 
        Beer.Hops, 
        Beer.SRM,
        Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) totalQuantity,
        CASE WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) < 0 THEN ''
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 1000 AND 4999 THEN 'Yellow'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) >= 5000 THEN 'GREEN'
        END
FROM    Beer
        INNER JOIN BeerStock
            ON Beer.Beer = BeerStock.Beer
-- Where    ..other conditions..
```

---

One more thing, You also need to use `GROUP BY` clause or else you will be returning only one record even if you have different records,

```
SELECT  Beer.Beer, 
        Beer.Brewery, 
        Beer.Style, 
        Beer.ABV, 
        Beer.Hops, 
        Beer.SRM,
        Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) totalQuantity,
        CASE WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) < 0 THEN ''
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 1000 AND 4999 THEN 'Yellow'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) BETWEEN 5000 AND 9999 THEN 'GREEN'
            WHEN Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) >= 10000 THEN 'Another Color' 
        END
FROM    Beer
        INNER JOIN BeerStock
            ON Beer.Beer = BeerStock.Beer
-- Where    ..other conditions..
GROUP   BY Beer.Beer, 
        Beer.Brewery, 
        Beer.Style, 
        Beer.ABV, 
        Beer.Hops, 
        Beer.SRM
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT Beer, Brewery, Style, ABV, SRM, SummedQty, 
    CASE 
       WHEN SummedQty >=0 AND SummedQty <= 1000 THEN ' RED'
       WHEN SummedQty >1000 AND SummedQty <= 5000 THEN ' YELLOW'
       WHEN SummedQty >5000 THEN ' GREEN'
       ELSE ''
    END yourcolor
FROM (
    SELECT Beer.Beer, Beer.Brewery, Beer.Style, Beer.ABV, Beer.Hops, Beer.SRM,
       Sum(BeerStock.Quantity) SummedQty
    FROM Beer
       INNER JOIN BeerStock  
          ON Beer.Beer = BeerStock.Beer
    ) t
```

Be careful using `BETWEEN` -- it may not return your desired results.  I prefer using greater than and less than.  I also converted your JOIN syntax to an `INNER JOIN`.