# Use Case statement to update table

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
UPDATE crm_accounts 
SET 
    reg = "Sim" 
WHERE age >= 17 
AND age <= 35 
AND balance > 0.00
AND type = "Júnior";


UPDATE crm_accounts 
SET 
    reg = "Não" 
WHERE age >= 17 
AND age <= 35 
AND balance = 0.00
AND type = "Júnior";


UPDATE crm_accounts 
SET 
    type = "Efetivo"
WHERE age >= 17
AND age <= 35 
AND type = "Júnior";
```

The statement work for the purpose but i want to simplify and combine in a case statement. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745186/180100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
 UPDATE crm_accounts a
    SET a.reg 
      = CASE
          WHEN a.balance > 0.00 THEN 'Sim'
          WHEN a.balance = 0.00 THEN 'Não'
          ELSE a.reg
        END
      , a.type = 'Efetivo'
  WHERE a.age >= 17
    AND a.age <= 35
    AND a.type = 'Júnior'
```

---

Whenever I'm writing update statements like this, I always test the expressions and predicates in a SELECT statement first, and verify the results. I make sure everything is working the way I need it to before I convert it to an UPDATE statement.

```
 SELECT a.age >= 17
      , a.type
      , a.reg AS old_reg
      , CASE
          WHEN a.balance > 0.00 THEN 'Sim'
          WHEN a.balance = 0.00 THEN 'Não'
          ELSE a.reg
        END AS new_reg
   FROM crm_accounts a
  WHERE a.age >= 17
    AND a.age <= 35
    AND a.type = 'Júnior'
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks for everything @spencer7593.

Comment: Note: I recommend that you use *single quotes* rather than *double quotes* to enclose string literals. Yes, MySQL does allow for string literals to be enclosed in double quotes. But other databases do not. And in MySQL, if `sql_mode` is changed to include `ANSI_QUOTES`, then MySQL will interpret double quotes to enclose *not* a string literal, but an *identifier* (e.g. a column name). Single quotes are standard  and will work with any `sql_mode` setting. The potential pitfalls of using double quotes around string literals outweighs any potential benefits.

Comment: you're right... i already have problems with the double quotes, but i always forget that...

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` Statements in MYSQL

There are  two syntax for CASE Statements

**SYNTAX 1:**

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

**SYNTAX 2:**

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

> **Explanation on Syntax One:**

For the first syntax, case_value is an expression. This value is compared to the when_value expression in each WHEN clause until one of them is equal. When an equal when_value is found, the corresponding THEN clause statement_list executes. If no when_value is equal, the ELSE clause statement_list executes, if there is one.

This syntax cannot be used to test for equality with NULL because NULL = NULL is false.

> **Explanation on Syntax Two:**

For the second syntax, each WHEN clause search_condition expression is evaluated until one is true, at which point its corresponding THEN clause statement_list executes. If no search_condition is equal, the ELSE clause statement_list executes, if there is one.

If no when_value or search_condition matches the value tested and the CASE statement contains no ELSE clause, a Case not found for CASE statement error results.

Each statement_list consists of one or more SQL statements; an empty statement_list is not permitted.

To handle situations where no value is matched by any WHEN clause, use an ELSE containing an empty BEGIN ... END block, as shown in this example. (The indentation used here in the ELSE clause is for purposes of clarity only, and is not otherwise significant.)

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE p()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;

    CASE v
      WHEN 2 THEN SELECT v;
      WHEN 3 THEN SELECT 0;
      ELSE            
        END;
    END CASE;
  END;
  |
```

And your Code can be Updated using the CASE Statements like this..

```
UPDATE `crm_accounts` SET `reg` = CASE

WHEN age >= 17 
AND age <= 35 
AND balance > 0.00
AND type = "Júnior" THEN "Sim"

WHEN age >= 17 
AND age <= 35 
AND balance = 0.00
AND type = "Júnior" THEN "Não"

WHEN age >= 17
AND age <= 35 
AND type = "Júnior" THEN "Efetivo"

ELSE `reg`

END
```

Comment: Hi Naresh. Thanks for your quick response and the explanation.

Comment: Not sure where you got that information about the ELSE clause in syntax two, but it is inaccurate. Omitting an ELSE clause merely means the CASE "returns" null if none of the when conditions are met; and when using a CASE in a query, I am fairly certain just the inclusion of BEGIN and END (that doesn't terminate the entire CASE) would cause problems. _Perhaps you were confusing the `CASE WHEN condition` used for queries, and the one used for procedural logic?_

Comment: @Uueerdo. I have got the info from the mysql.com alone and i have used this else part to for one of my projects ...

Comment: @NareshKumar.P You've used `CASE .... ELSE BEGIN ...` within a **query**?

Comment: @Uueerdo.I have removed the `BEGIN` in the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` Statement. Is this now correct..

Comment: This is *not* correct. `CASE` is a standard SQL ***expression*** supported in MySQL and a long list of other relational databases. We should take care not to conflate the SQL standard `CASE` ***expression*** with a `CASE` ***statement***, which is an entirely different beast. This answer dumps documentation/explanation about the `CASE` *statement*, and demonstrates the use of a `CASE` *statement* in a MySQL stored program, and then (erroneously) suggests that a `CASE` *statement* can be used in an `UPDATE` statement. *That's wrong.* A `CASE` *expression* can be used in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: The UPDATE statement proposed in this answer will assign the string `'Efetivo'` to the `reg` column. The UPDATE statements in the question seem to indicate that string `Efetivo` should be assigned to the `type` column, not the `reg` column.