# How to run SELECT statement based on the results of other columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `col1` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `col2` varchar(45) DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And it contains the following data:

[image]

How can I use `SELECT` statement to generate a result like this:

[image]

The meaning of the content of `check` column is as the following:

```
`both` when both `col1` and `col2` have values.
`left` when only `col1` has a value.
`rightest` when only `col2` has a value.
`empty` when both `col1` and `col2` has empty value.
```

I think the query would look like something like this one

```
# something must be used to replace ???
SELECT (???) AS check, col1, col2 FROM my_table;
```

where `???` should be changed to something else.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: You can use `case when` and Switch the result in each case. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745186/11005027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = '' and col2='' then 'Empty'
            WHEN col1 = '' then 'Right'
            WHEN col2='' then 'Left'
            else 'Both' end as 'Check',
        col1, col2 FROM yourtablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query -

```
select
col1, col2,
case 
when (nvl(col1) or col1='') and (nvl(col2) or col2='') then 'empty'
when (nvl(col1) or col1='') and (col2<>'') then 'right'
when (col1<>'') and (nvl(col2) or col2='') then 'left'
else 'Both' end as col3 from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN could do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = '' 
            THEN CASE WHEN col2 = '' 
                      THEN 'empty'
                      ELSE 'right'
                 END
            ELSE CASE WHEN col2 = ''
                      THEN 'left'
                      ELSE 'both'
       END AS check,
       col1, col2 FROM my_table
```